# In Linux shell or awk, how to replace the url in a line with its domain

Tags: regex, bash, shell, url, awk

For example, the input:

```
line1 col1-1 http://www.google.com/index.html col3-1 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line2 col1-2 https://user:pwd@www.facebook.com/pp/index.html col3-2 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line3 col1-3 badColumn col3-3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

Should results in

```
line1 col1-1 http://www.google.com col3-1 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line2 col1-2 https://www.facebook.com col3-2 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line3 col1-3 badColumn col3-3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

It is possible to achieve it with `awk` one linear (`sub` and `regex`?) Otherwise, how would you implement it in bash?

Answer (score 5):

I think it would probably be better to use a URL parser. For example, Python has: [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) which can be used to parse URLs into components. Here's some example code, run like:

```
python3 script.py file
```

Contents of `script.py`:

```
import sys
import csv
from urllib.parse import urlparse


with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as csvfile:

    r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')

    for row in r:

        url = urlparse(row[2]);

        if (url.scheme and url.hostname):

            row[2] = url.scheme + "://" + url.hostname

        print(' '.join(row))
```

Results:

```
line1 col1-1 http://www.google.com col3-1 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line2 col1-2 https://www.facebook.com col3-2 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line3 col1-3 badColumn col3-3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most beautiful regexp, but in sed :

```
$ sed -r 's|://([^/]*@)?([^/]*)[^ \t]*|://\2|g' < myfile
line1 col1-1 http://www.google.com/ col8
line2 col1-2 https://user:pwd@www.facebook.com/ col8
line3 col1-3 badColumn col3-3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU awk` you can do:

```
gawk '$3~/http/{$3=gensub(/([^/]+)\/\/([^/]+).*/,"\\1//\\2","g",$3);gsub(/\/\/.*www/,"//www",$3)}1' file
```

```
$ cat file
line1 col1-1 http://www.google.com/index.html col3-1 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line2 col1-2 https://user:pwd@www.facebook.com/pp/index.html col3-2 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line3 col1-3 badColumn col3-3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

```
$ awk '$3~/http/{$3=gensub(/([^/]+)\/\/([^/]+).*/,"\\1//\\2","g",$3);gsub(/\/\/.*www/,"//www",$3)}1' file
line1 col1-1 http://www.google.com col3-1 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line2 col1-2 https://user:pwd@www.facebook.com col3-2 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line3 col1-3 badColumn col3-3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

Comment: @anubhava Oops, good catch. Though I think the answer has become more fragile to handle different use cases. `:(`. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another  `awk`

```
awk '/http/ {split($3,a,"/");sub(/^.*@/,"",a[3]);$3=a[1]"//"a[3]}8' file
line1 col1-1 http://www.google.com col3-1 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line2 col1-2 https://www.facebook.com col3-2 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
line3 col1-3 badColumn col3-3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
```

Answer (score 0):

replace "//user:password@"   with   "//"

```
sed 's:/.*@://:g' inputfile
```

Comment: What if col7 is an email address?

Answer (score 0):

My quick & dirty sed solution would be this:

```
sed 's#//[^@]*@#//#;s#\([^/]\)/[^/][^ ]* #\1 #' file1
```

which like the others here doesn't restrict its activity to just the third column.  This relies on the idea that the first non-doubled slash in the URL is where you want to start stripping, and that those magic double slashes don't appear anywhere else on the line.

To restrict things to just the third column, awk seems like a good bet.  But you can't do backreferences using `sub()` or `gsub()` functions in most awk implementations, but you can use them in GAWK's `gensub()`, like this:

```
gawk '{$3=gensub(/\/\/([^@\/]+@)?([^\/]+).*/, "//\\2", "g", $3)} 1' file1
```

This is similar to but simpler than jaypal's solution as it uses only a single substitution, and it doesn't require that "www" be part of the hostname.

But you can also do this in pure bash:

```sh
while read one two three four; do
  method=${three%//*}
  host=${three#*//}
  host=${host#*@}
  host=${host%/*}
  three="$method//$host"
  echo "$one $two $three $four"
done < file1
```

Yep. You can do anything in bash.  It just takes more typing.  :)